# Is there an elegant way to override a testbench parameter from the test besides defparam in SystemVerilog

Tags: parameters, overriding, system-verilog

This is an environment that is not UVM based but I have a testbench and multiple tests. The tests and testbench are all the top-level but will optimize one test and the testbench for a single run and reoptimize with another test for the next run and so on. This allows a single testbench and compilation of all the sources once and optimize and simulate on a test basis. I have the following piece of code that had issues with the simulator which is a bug because I don't see anything wrong from an LRM point of view. Also, since defparam is getting deprecated in future I was wondering what's the best way to achieve this behavior?. I would prefer not to use defines and override it from command line because I will be dealing with a lot of parameters.

Here's the code that has a problem with simulation:

```
module test_tb();

  
   parameter int  NUM_LAYERS                       = 3;
   parameter int  NUM_NS_PER_LAYER[NUM_LAYERS]     = '{8,8,8};


      initial
        begin
         #100;
         $display ("NUM_LAYERS is %d and NUM_NS_PER_LAYER is %p", NUM_LAYERS, NUM_NS_PER_LAYER);
         $display ("NUM_LAYERS is %d ", NUM_LAYERS);
        end
endmodule


module test();

   localparam int NS                                             = 1;
   localparam int NSP[NS]                                        = '{4};
   defparam test_tb.NUM_LAYERS                                   = 1;
   // The following 2 lines fail with simulators but some simulators will accept it if I uncomment the next line and comment out the line after it.
   //defparam test_tb.NUM_NS_PER_LAYER                             = NSP;
   defparam test_tb.NUM_NS_PER_LAYER                             = '{4};


endmodule
```

defparam is an elegant way to do this but is there something that can be done with class and override the parameters but make it available within the testbech.

Comment: *defparam* is an *ugly* way and could be rmoved from the standard eventually :-).  You should use parameterized modules instead (or parameterized classes). Check the manual.

Answer (score 1):

You could instantiate the test_tb in the test?

```
module test();
 
   localparam int NS                              = 1;
   localparam int NSP[NS]                         = '{4};
 
  test_tb #(NS,NSP) tb();
 
endmodule
```

You can still keep the compilation separate.

Comment: Yes I have begun to accept this as the best approach from the options out there.